# Create Modal with reactjs bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am getting kind of desperated. I want to make an modal dialog in reactjs using bootstrap. I have installed the module with npm and imported it in my code. I tried a simple example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


class Config extends React.Component {


constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {

        show: false
    }
    this.handleHide = this.handleHide.bind(this);

}


handleHide() {
    this.setState({ show: false });
}

render(){


    return ( <div>
            <Button
                bsStyle="primary"
                bsSize="large"
                onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true })}
            >
                Launch modal
            </Button>

            <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleHide}>
                <Modal.Header >
                   Header
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    Text
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.handleHide}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
    </div>)
}

}

export default Config;
```

I dont get any error, but I also cant see anything, if I click on the button. I looked with the Chrome developer tool through the Elements and I can see the modal there, which is confusing.
Does someone has an idea what is wrong?

Comment: Hmm.. I ran into the same issue the other day. What I did however was have 2 different functions for the modal. One for the Handleshow and one for the HandleClose and it worked for me I can show you my example if you want.

Comment: @Curious13 I tried it, but still don't work. I would be still grateful if you show your code, maybe you did something different

Comment: try to replace handleHide function with this.<br>
 `this.setState({`
      `show: !this.state.show`
   ` });`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me it's almost identical to your example. However, instead of using one function to handle the state by itself, I used 2 functions for the `handleClose` and `HandleShow`.

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            show: false
        }
    }

    handleClose(){
        this.setState({
            show:false
        });
    }

    handleShow(){
        this.setState({
            show:true
        });
    }

    render(){

        // console.log(this.state);

        return (
            <div className="header-container">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/Contact">Contact</Link></li>
                        <li><Button className="login-button" onClick={this.handleShow}>LOGIN</Button></li>
                    </ul>
                    <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                        <Modal.Header closeButton>
                            <Modal.Title>Modal Header</Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            Modal Body
                        </Modal.Body>
                    </Modal>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: don't work for me, but thanks. I will try some other things

Comment: really? thats interesting. I'm using that code example right now and it works fine for me. Sorry I couldn't help.